# How to find write usages to variable, field and property using ReSharper

Tags: resharper

How to find all the places in code where a specific property (or field or variable) has it's value set using ReSharper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ReSharper`->`Find`->`Find Usages` (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> Visual Studio keymap scheme or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> IntelliJ keymap scheme) and use the `Show Only Read Usages` or `Show Only Write Usages` buttons:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put the cursor over the "field" and press ctrl+shift+alt+a